# How can I run a command in an nginx container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a front end project and I can customize it by specifying environments in my front project thanks to the sh scripts I place in it while building. My sample compose file is as follows. Everything I wrote in the command section works fine in my k8s deployment.yaml file, but I get an error in compose yml and the commands I write in command do not work.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    image: imagename:tag
    command: bash -c "
      if [ -s /var/www/set_env.sh ]; then
      mv /var/www/set_env.sh /mnt;
      fi;
      chmod +x /mnt/set_env.sh;
      /mnt/set_env.sh;
      rm /mnt/set_env.sh;"
    environment:
      SYSTEM: 'system'
      COMPANY: 'company'
      API_URL: 'https://'
      SITEKEY_LOGGER: 'logger'
      SITEKEY_CAPTCHA: 'captcha_key'
    # restart: always
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: '512m'
    ports:
      -  "18001:80"
```

The error I got for the compose above is;
`nginx: invalid option: "bash"`
I tried other ways but couldn't find how to run command in compose file for my front project.
The Dockerfile I use for the service is as follows;

```
FROM node:12.18.3-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PROFILE=basic
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Note: In this situation, I need to be able to run command in compose. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `command` option in a docker-compose file, whatever you specify is passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` of the Dockerfile as parameter. So here, your command becomes something like `nginx -g "daemon off;" bash -c ...`. Thus you get the error `nginx: invalid option: "bash"`

What I would advice :

- Create a file, `entrypoint.sh` for example, with whatever you want to execute inside, the last line `exec "$@` will run the container command :

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ -s /var/www/set_env.sh ]; then
    mv /var/www/set_env.sh /mnt
fi
chmod +x /mnt/set_env.sh
/mnt/set_env.sh
rm /mnt/set_env.sh

exec "$@"
```

- Copy this file inside your Docker image, then set the script as `ENTRYPOINT` and nginx startup as `CMD`

```
FROM node:12.18.3-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PROFILE=basic
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

- Remove the `command` from your docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    image: imagename:tag
    environment:
      SYSTEM: 'system'
      COMPANY: 'company'
      API_URL: 'https://'
      SITEKEY_LOGGER: 'logger'
      SITEKEY_CAPTCHA: 'captcha_key'
    # restart: always
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: '512m'
    ports:
      -  "18001:80"
```

Now, when you start your container, `entrypoint.sh` is used as entrypoint, executing the commands specified in the Dockerfile. The command could be easily overwritten in the docker-compose file if needed.

Hope this helps !

Edit: Edit answer following @David Maze's advices !

Comment: I would make the last line of the entrypoint script be `exec "$@"` to run the container command, and then set the image's `CMD` to launch Nginx.  You are forced to repeat the `CMD` when you override the `ENTRYPOINT`.  `COPY` the script into the image; do not mount code using `volumes:`, and for this use case do not override `entrypoint:` at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I edited my answer. If he can edit the Dockerfile that's indeed better !

Comment: Greetings, unfortunately the pod is not working despite running the commands. When I check the log, nothing appears.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is using `bash` to run the script.
Nginx image doesn't have `bash` by default, use `sh` to run your script.
simply replace bash with sh in the command section.
you might want to add `nginx -s reload` to reload nginx if your script changes something related.